# Как сделать многоуровневое reply-меню телеграмм бота, библиотека pytelegrambotapi python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, бот

Есть код, с двух уровневым меню, помогите в разделе "многоразовые под-системы" сделать меню с 3 разделами(Н: многоразовые под-системы -> smoant -> knigt, под-системы -> smoant -> pasito и дальше список моделей этого производителя).Пока что только под-системы -> smoant

```
import telebot
import random
import sqlite3

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")
db = sqlite3.connect('db.db')



@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
sti = open("File/hi.webp", "rb")
bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)
mess = f"Привет, {message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name} я твой личный помощник в выборе товара в магазине TumanPlace"
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Жидкости")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Одноразовые pod-системы")
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Многоразовые pod-системы")
        btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Наша локация')
        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, btn4)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, parse_mode="html")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Чем я могу помочь?", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def items(message):
    get_message_bot = message.text

    @bot.message_handler(commands=["address"])
    def address(message):
        bot.send_location(message.chat.id, 56.144607, 40.419294)

    if get_message_bot == "начать тест заново":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Жидкости')
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Одноразовые pod-системы')
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Многоразовые pod-системы')
        btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Наша локация')
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4)

        final_message = "Чтобы вы хотели выбрать?"

    elif get_message_bot == "Жидкости":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('SOAK')
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('HASKY')
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('ЧТО-НИБУДЬ')
        btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('DUALL')
        btn5 = types.KeyboardButton('KAPUSTA')
        btn6 = types.KeyboardButton('RELL')
        btn7 = types.KeyboardButton('HOTSPOT')
        btn8 = types.KeyboardButton('PLATINUM')
        btn9 = types.KeyboardButton('MRAZZI')
        btn10 = types.KeyboardButton('BOSHKI')
        btn11 = types.KeyboardButton('DABLER')
        btn12 = types.KeyboardButton('PADONKI')
        btn13 = types.KeyboardButton('МИШКА')
        btn14 = types.KeyboardButton('GLITCH SALT')
        btn15 = types.KeyboardButton("Начать тест заново")
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn10, btn11, btn12, btn13, btn14, btn15)

        final_message = "Отлично, выберите еще пожалуйста"

    elif get_message_bot == "Одноразовые pod-системы":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('WIPO')
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('PUFFMI')
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('LOST MARY')
        btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('SNOWWOOF')
        btn5 = types.KeyboardButton('ATTACKER')
        btn6 = types.KeyboardButton('SUPSMOK')
        btn7 = types.KeyboardButton('HQD')
        btn8 = types.KeyboardButton('LIO')
        btn9 = types.KeyboardButton('LIO&UDN')
        btn10 = types.KeyboardButton('LIO BOOM')
        btn11 = types.KeyboardButton('ELFBAR')
        btn12 = types.KeyboardButton('DRAGBAR')
        btn13 = types.KeyboardButton('SOAK')
        btn14 = types.KeyboardButton('UDN GEN')
        btn15 = types.KeyboardButton("Начать тест заново")
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn10, btn11, btn12, btn13, btn14, btn15)

        final_message = "Отлично, выберите еще пожалуйста"

    elif get_message_bot == "Многоразовые pod-системы":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Smoant')
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Vaporesso')
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('GeekVape')
        btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('VooPoo')
        btn5 = types.KeyboardButton('JellyBox')
        btn6 = types.KeyboardButton('Brusko')
        btn7 = types.KeyboardButton('Rincoe')
        btn8 = types.KeyboardButton('Nevoks')
        btn9 = types.KeyboardButton('Smok')
        btn10 = types.KeyboardButton("Начать тест заново")
        final_message = "Осталось выбрать бренд который вам понравится :)"
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9)

        @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
        def items2(message):
            get_message_bot = message.text
            if get_message_bot == "Smoant":
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('PASITO II')
                btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('CHARON BABY')
                btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('CHARON BABY PLUS')
                btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('KNIGHT 80')
                btn5 = types.KeyboardButton('PASITO MINI')
                btn6 = types.KeyboardButton('SANTI')
                btn7 = types.KeyboardButton('KNIGHT 40')
                btn8 = types.KeyboardButton("Начать тест заново")
                markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8)
                final_message = "***ИНФОРМАЦИЯ***"

            elif get_message_bot == "Vaporesso":
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('XROS')
                btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('XROS 2')
                btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('XROS 3')
                btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('XROS mini')
                btn5 = types.KeyboardButton('XTRA')
                btn6 = types.KeyboardButton("Начать тест заново")
                markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6)
                final_message = "***ИНФОРМАЦИЯ***"

            elif get_message_bot == "GeekVape":
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('HERO H45')
                btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('HERO')
                btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('B100')
                btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('NANO')
                btn5 = types.KeyboardButton('ONE')
                btn6 = types.KeyboardButton('OBELISK 65PS')
                btn7 = types.KeyboardButton("Начать тест заново")
                markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7)
                final_message = "***ИНФОРМАЦИЯ***"

            elif get_message_bot == "VooPoo":
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('DRAG S')
                btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('DRAG X')
                btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('DRAG H80S')
                btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('DRAG X PRO')
                btn5 = types.KeyboardButton('DRAG S PRO')
                btn6 = types.KeyboardButton('DRAG NANO 2')
                btn7 = types.KeyboardButton('ARGUS AIR')
                btn8 = types.KeyboardButton('ARGUS')
                btn9 = types.KeyboardButton('VTHRU PRO')
                btn10 = types.KeyboardButton('VTHRU')
                btn11 = types.KeyboardButton('VINCI')
                btn12 = types.KeyboardButton("Начать тест заново")
                markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn10, btn11, btn12)
                final_message = "***ИНФОРМАЦИЯ***"

            elif get_message_bot == "JellyBox":
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('NANO')
                btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('AIR X')
                btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Начать тест заново")
                markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
                final_message = "***ИНФОРМАЦИЯ***"

            elif get_message_bot == "Brusko":
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('MINICAN')
                btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('MINICAN 2')
                btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('MINICAN PLUS')
                btn4 = types.KeyboardButton("Начать тест заново")
                markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4)
                final_message = "***ИНФОРМАЦИЯ***"

            elif get_message_bot == "Rincoe":
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('MANTO AIO')
                btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('MANTO AIO PLUS')
                btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Начать тест заново")
                markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
                final_message = "***ИНФОРМАЦИЯ***"

            elif get_message_bot == "Nevoks":
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('FEELIN')
                btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('FEELIN X')
                btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Начать тест заново")
                markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
                final_message = "***ИНФОРМАЦИЯ***"

            elif get_message_bot == "Smok":
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('RPM 4')
                btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('RPM 3')
                btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('NFIX')
                btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('NOVO 2')
                btn5 = types.KeyboardButton('NORD PRO')
                btn6 = types.KeyboardButton("Начать тест заново")
                markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6)
                final_message = "***ИНФОРМАЦИЯ***"

            else:
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
                btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Smoant')
                btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Vaporesso')
                btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('GeekVape')
                btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('VooPoo')
                btn5 = types.KeyboardButton('JellyBox')
                btn6 = types.KeyboardButton('Brusko')
                btn7 = types.KeyboardButton('Rincoe')
                btn8 = types.KeyboardButton('Nevoks')
                btn9 = types.KeyboardButton('Smok')
                btn10 = types.KeyboardButton("Начать тест заново")
                markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn10)
                final_message = "Ой неполадка :)"


    elif message.text == "Наша локация":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        bot.send_location(message.chat.id, 56.144607, 40.419294)
        final_message = "Мы здесь"
    else:
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Жидкости')
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Одноразовые pod-системы')
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Многоразовые pod-системы')
        btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Наша локация')
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4)

        final_message = "Выберите тип товара"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, final_message, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Делайте через инлайн-кнопки, к каждому ответу крепите callback_data и по ней вызываете нужный ответ с последующей нужной клавиатурой(Имхо, будет лучше выглядеть)

Если хотите именно через reply-кнопки, то ловите текст и по нему таким же принципом делаете ветки ответов:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def test(message: types.Message):
    if message.text =='Начать Тест':
        #начинаете тест
    elif message.text =='Вариант ответа 1':
        #дальше продолжаете ветку
    elif message.text =='Вариант ответа 2':
        #заканчиваете ветку или делаете нужные Вам действия
```

Для красоты, после каждого варианта ответа удалять предыдущее сообение бота через:

```
bot.delete_message()
```